# Get number of cells in Grid panel and access them

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Is it possible to know the number of cells in a Grid? Could I access them in some way to append a child to each of them?

For example, if I have a 2 rows x 3 columns Grid:

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>

   <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I have tried something like:

```
foreach (RowDefinition row in this.myGrid.RowDefinitions)
{
    foreach(ColumnDefinition col in row)
    {
        // This doesn't work.
        // There is no property ColumnDefinitions in row.
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to achive this (if possible).

Comment: @mm8 Sorry, I'm afraid I don't know what do you mean

Comment: in the given xaml sample there are 3 `<Grid>` elements  instead of one which has 2 rows and 3 columns

Comment: Hmm... ok. Actually, I'm new to WPF, and I have learned this way. But maybe is better to do it the way you say?

Answer (score 1):

RowDefinitions and ColumnDefinitions belong to Grid and they are independent from each other.

fix xaml definition to make a 2x3 Grid (instead of current 2x1, 1x3, 1x3 Grids)

```
<Grid Name="myGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Grid cells are not represented by any control. They are just rectangular areas in Grid, determined during arrange. Use `Grid.RowProperty` and `Grid.ColumnProperty` attached DP to position child elements in Grid:

```
for(int r = 0; r < myGrid.RowDefinitions.Count; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Count; c++)
    {
        var B = new Border { Margin = new Thickness(5), Background = Brushes.Green };
        B.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, r);
        B.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, c);
        myGrid.Children.Add(B);
    }
}
```

if all cells are of equal size, you can use UniformGrid:

```
<UniformGrid Name="myGrid" Rows="2" Columns="3"/>

for(int r = 0; r < myGrid.Rows; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < myGrid.Columns; c++)
    {
        var B = new Border { Margin = new Thickness(5), Background = Brushes.Green };
        myGrid.Children.Add(B);
    }
}
```